# Encryption between Android and C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, android, encryption

I am using the following C# source code to encrypt plain text using AES (ECB 256):

```
public static string Encode(string PlainText)
{
 byte[] Key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678901234567890123456789012");
 string encrypted = null;


 RijndaelManaged rj = new RijndaelManaged();
 rj.BlockSize = 256;
 rj.KeySize = 256;
 rj.Key = Key;
 rj.GenerateIV();

 byte[] IV  = rj.IV;
 rj.Mode    = CipherMode.ECB;
 rj.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

 try
 {
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
   using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
   {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
    {
     sw.Write(PlainText);
     sw.Close();
     sw.Dispose();
    }

    cs.Close();
    cs.Dispose();
   }

   byte[] encryptArray = ms.ToArray();

   encrypted = (Convert.ToBase64String(encryptArray));

   ms.Close();
   ms.Dispose();
  }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  throw ex;
 }

 finally
 {
  rj.Clear();
 }

 return encrypted;
}
```

And I need decrypt/encrypt data through same algorithm, but I don't know how.

Here my Java Class (**not working**):

```
 public static String encrypt(byte[] key, String cleartext, boolean base64) throws Exception
 {
  byte[] rawKey   = key;
  byte[] result   = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());

  // Base 64
  if (base64)
   return toBase64(result);

  // Hex
  return toHex(result);
 }

 public static String decrypt(byte[] key, String encrypted)
   throws Exception
 {
  byte[] rawKey = key;
  byte[] enc    = toByte(encrypted);
  byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

  return new String(result);
 }

 private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception
 {
  SecretKeySpec skeySpec          = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
  Cipher cipher                   = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");

  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

  byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);

  return encrypted;
 }
```

Java call:

```
encrypt("12345678901234567890123456789012".getBytes(), "Example Message", true);
```

I dont know how I can select the block size or the *PaddingMode.Zeros* in Java.

**¿Any idea?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've discovered the problem. My Java code is using AES-128 (block size 128) and the C# code is using AES-256 (real block size 256). So, somebody knows how use AES-256 in Java?

Comment: How are you generating the key in Java (i.e. the 'key' parameter in your first encrypt() method)?

Comment: In response to your comment I think I've read somewhere that only AES-128 is actually standardized, the others are not. You get the same problem when ciphering stuff between a .NET C# application and one executed with Mono (IIRC). [Mono related reference](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-list@lists.ximian.com/msg18570.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the limit of **128 bits** block size in AES (see '*Strong Versus Unlimited Strength Cryptography*').

Finally, I've used [GNU Crypto](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/) and it works!. I've imported all source code and I've deleted the code that I'm not using.

If somebody wants the ***cleaned* source code** he only have to ask me.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should also consider Bouncy Castle, it's available for both C# and Java

http://www.bouncycastle.org

Answer (score 1):

Reading over [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html) article, it seems you might need to use a version of Java that allows unlimited strength cryptography so that you can use large key sizes (AES-192 and AES-256). They intentionally limit the key lengths that can be used by default due to import-control restrictions imposed by some countries. See the 'Strong Versus Unlimited Strength Cryptography' section for more information.